# How to automatically add articles in Google Scholar profile for journal?

Tags: publications, google-scholar

**Is it possible to automatically add publications to a journal's Google Scholar profile?**

I know this is possible for a person's profile, because Google automatically find and adds the publications where that person is an author.

But in the case of a journal, there are numerous publications with different authors and I don't know if Google can recognize that they belong to that journal in order to automatically add them. The common criteria for automatically adding the articles should be the journal's name.

Comment: What do you mean by "journal's Google Scholar profile"? AFAIK only authors can have profiles.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I mean that some journals may have their own Google Scholar profile, such as MDPI Robotics (https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=8IcRkC8AAAAJ&hl=en) or JEEECCS (https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=FbHEejkAAAAJ&hl=ro&authuser=2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, you list two examples:

- [Robotics](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=8IcRkC8AAAAJ&hl=en) (by MDPI), and
- [JEEECCS](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=FbHEejkAAAAJ&hl=en)

Interestingly, Google Scholar (GS) profiles are meant to showcase *authors*' research, and not *journals*' research. ([Cf. GS' self-description](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=FbHEejkAAAAJ&hl=en).)

Consequently, GS contains a function that can algorithmically add new publications to your profile based on *author names*. But it does not provide such an automatic function based on *journal names*.

Thus, if you maintain a Google Scholar profile for a journal, then you need to add all publications manually.

Comment: Ok. So the short answer is no. Thank you.